# How to create an Electron Monaco Editor Language server client and server?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am using electron to create a custom IDE, and using Monaco Editor as the editor. I want to integrate PHP Intellisense, but Im having a problem. Here is the link to the PHP Language Server: https://github.com/bmewburn/intelephense-docs/blob/master/installation.md and it connects via IPC. But the https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient connects via websockets. How do I connect the client to the server via IPC?

Comment: The first link you provide states that is supports sockets via `--socket={number}`. Wouldn't it be easier using this?

Comment: hmm... but what do i put in the number param?

Comment: Just thinking, not saying it will work for sure: I'm guessing you'll have to choose a number in your Electron app, and use that same number on Monaco's end, and on the language server's end when you launch it from there. It's the port number

Comment: how do i use IPC? do i need another language client package? this seems to be the only one for monaco

Comment: ok i think i will stick to websockets. but how does the client in the example https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/blob/master/example/src/client.ts know which events to send to the server?